# Load OpenRailwayMap layer in Google Maps

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, railroad

I'm quite new using Javascript Google maps API, and I need to create a simple map showing the railways in Europe.

I was thinkin in downloading the data from OSM and show it in my map, but I'm sure there is a simple way to do it, showing the data directly from OpenRailwayMap as a WMS-like layer.

Does somebody know if could be possible do it like this?

Comment: You can use the OpenRailwayMap tiles directly but under certain conditions as described here in the documentation: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenRailwayMap/API

Comment: Thanks. I see usage for OL and Leaflet. Is it possible to use it with GMaps too?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try to adapt this: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Google_Maps_Example with the tiles from OpenRailwayMap.